# How does Stack Overflow keep track of visit timestamps?

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I visited Stack Overflow consecutively for quite some time. I remember this day when I went home, and in the meantime I probably didn't visit SO for over 24 hours or so. But I did visit on Apr 5<sup>th</sup> 2014. Still SO didn't record that I visited that day.

Is this a bug, or does SO behave this way by design?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two aspects that are important and may confuse you:

1. Stack Overflow days start and end at UTC 00:00. If you are not in Britain during wintertime, that's not ever your own timezone. Your midnight is not going to coincide with the site midnight. You can see the current time in UTC by looking at the achievements drop-down (the icon with the bars on it in the top-bar, click on that).
2. Merely logging in doesn't count as enough activity. What *is* considered enough is not public, but you need to do more than just look at the frontpage or your profile.

Comment: thanks that clears my confusion then :)

Comment: Logging in (on my phone), opening my profile and clicking on the counter to display the calendar, was enough for me to make a day count as *visited*.

Comment: @Stijn: I am merely reporting on what [Jef Atwood](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485) has stated about what counts in the past.

Comment: Yeah I figured you were quoting it from somewhere, perhaps it has changed. (I got here via [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265240/weekday-warrior-badge#comment58904_265240))

Comment: @Stijn: as the calendar popup is a separate AJAX request, you did more than logging in there.

Comment: I'm a victim of #2 and I really wondering as during normal workday I'm visiting a lot of pages, question. Not always voting or commenting, but reading. Little unfair.

Comment: This is wrong/outdated... I did #2 many days for the fanatic badge

Comment: @AlecAlameddine: no, this is not outdated. You did not meet the criteria for the badge, which are *not made public*. So you can't know what you need to do *exactly* to get the badge.

Comment: Then why do I have the badge?

Comment: @AlecAlameddine: right, I misunderstood what you meant there. You are saying you only logged in.  But *what page did you look at*? Again, the activity required is not public, so it is *impossible to say* if this information is wrong or outdated. What I report here is what the developers have reported.

Comment: I bookmarked the profile tab of my profile page (as opposed to the default activity tab when looking at your own profile). That seemed to be enough to count

Comment: @AlecAlameddine: with the emphasis on 'seemed'. That's not advice I'm willing to pass on to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow runs on UTC.

If you did not visit within a UTC day, that day will not be marked.

If you visited, but were not logged in, it will not be marked (as we don't know it was you).

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange "day" is aligned with UTC.

So depending on where you are in the world and whether or not you have daylight saving time you might find that visiting twice on the same local day is regarded as visits on consecutive UTC "days" while visits on consecutive local days is regarded as visits on the same UTC "day" or (annoyingly) visits on non consecutive UTC "days".