# Active on the site from multiple devices but "consecutive days visited" count does not increase

Tags: support, login, consecutive-days

Why doesn't Stack Overflow track the number of days that I've visited the site? I remain logged in from my home PC and log in from my phone, tablet, and work PC, but the consecutive days visited count keeps dropping. Does anyone know why this is? I'm usually on the site a few times every few hours, so I can't figure out why the system thinks I'm not logged in.

[How does Stack Overflow keep track of visit timestamps?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251762/how-does-stack-overflow-keep-track-of-visit-timestamps) explains how time zones affect this, which I'm not asking about. It also explains that only staring at your own profile page doesn't count as activity. This doesn't apply to me. I'm **logged in consistently so timezone is irrelevant** and I'm **not simply sitting at my profile page**.

Please describe exactly what activity is needed to count as a "visit". Everyone says to not sit on the profile page. I'm **not** doing that. What qualifies as a "certain amount of activity"?  I want to know why the consecutive day count does not rise even though I'm NEVER logging out and consistently browsing different posts, starring posts I like, and upvoting answers that helped.

As a new member, is it even possible to maintain my login state, considering the lack of things I can do on the site?  Is it just impossible to get the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges as a new user? What else could I possibly do to stay logged in?

Comment: As Jon Clements said in [his comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265193/website-doesnt-track-days-visited#comment58555_265193) to your previous question: You need to perform a certain amount of activity **(which as far as I'm aware isn't disclosed to avoid abuse)**.

Comment: If you want to explain why your post is not a duplicate, **DON'T** post another question. Edit your original post and/or add a comment. Posting again will just get your post close... As a duplicate... Of your original question.

Comment: I couldn't. It kept saying closed entry or need 50 to comment once it was listed as duplicate

Comment: If someone flags duplicate and editing doesnt change status, I'm not sure what other option I was supposed to take, especially if I can't participate in the question that the person marked as duplicate....  It just locked everything and stopped me from getting any answers. So, ya, I posted the question again but with more details.   Frederic, how do you know it's due to abuse? I'm not sure I understand how that causes abuse?  I just don't understand why the system thinks I'm logging out or not doing anything when I clearly am. the duplicate people keep posting isn't answering my question

Comment: @cjayem13, I don't *know it's due to abuse*, I was repeating Jon's point that the exact details of the activities required to count as a "day visited" are not public *to avoid abuse*. Not the same thing :)

Comment: **Don't just repost your question when you don't agree it is a dupe**. I'm sorry, but your post *was **very much** a duplicate*.

Comment: I already stated **both in the dupe answer** and in a comment to your now deleted post, that **the exact activities required** is ***not public***. That means that there is no more information to give you than what is already posted in the other answer.