# Can't get my question answered due to duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, meta

Someone marked [my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265198/website-doesnt-track-days-visited) as a duplicate, but when I read the post they flagged as duplicate, it doesn't answer the question I initially asked at all.

I tried editing the post but it stays listed as duplicate. Now people overlook my initial question assuming that it's being answered, but it isn't.  I can't participate in the "duplicate" post either because it says I need 50 reputation.

I tried rewording , adding details, clarifying why it's not a duplicate, and re-asking, but it's flagged as duplicate and I can't undo it. What can I do?

As I don't have a high reputation, so my options are limited. I'm not sure what else to do besides open another account.  Please help someone.

Comment: Just calm down! Take a deep breath, look out the window.. chill

Comment: Just be patient -- reopening a closed post *usually* takes time, due to the 5 reopen votes needed from normal viewers. Edits may not get noticed right away.

Comment: why was my question voted down?  is asking how to participate already answered?  I don't understand how this site works.  I cna't participate but I lose points when asking questions? how's this work?

Comment: I would imagine it's because this question reads more like a rant than a constructive question looking for support or input. If you try to rephrase it, concisely, and perhaps use paragraphs to organise your thoughts...

Comment: o wow. how so? I provided details as to why I'm getting the problems.  Why can't something I'm frustrated with spark a question?

Comment: First of all - do you mean here on meta, or on Stack Overflow? Please be clear. Be calm. Take a deep breath.

Comment: O both. I'm not trying to come across rude or anything. I'm just highly confused. People keep voting my question down and I'm not sure why.   I'm simply trying to figure out, if my question, especially on stackoverflow in the programmers section, is flagged as duplicate how can I either participate in the duplicate to insure my question is answered or edit my question and remove the duplicate.

Comment: You know you can always add comments on your own questions - even when they are closed

Comment: When you edit your own questions, and they are closed, they will enter the "reopen vote" queue, to be reviewed by people who have the privilege to review such things. If you've added enough details to differentiate your question from the duplicate, your question will most likely be reopened in a while.

Comment: I *thought* you're always allowed to comment on your own posts, but apparently not after your post is closed? That's new to me. And you can't unmark your question as dupe yourself. Either a mod or 5 voters have to do that.

Comment: it started with asking a question about how to implement onClick for fragments and another for the login status and consecutive days on profile.  While posting about onClick for android I lost my consecutive days count and I asked why, someone said lack of activity in a duplicate and time zone issues in another but neither applied to my case but since it was posted as duplicate, I wasn't getting responses.. I edited, re-posted, and same thing. the same user listed as duplicate. Maybe this is a rant, but it's still a question... how can I participate in duplicates or unflag after edit?

Comment: Why are you asking for advise here, but refuse to elaborate which specific question of yours and which duplicate you're actually referring to?

Comment: Huh? I just explained what lead up to this. Where else should I ask for advise?

Comment: It's hard to advise on specifics of why something was closed without knowing any specifics or seeing the question/edit history/comments. Can you post a link?

Comment: The second time your consecutive-days question was voted to close as a duplicate, it was as a duplicate of your original consecutive-days question. We as a community tend to frown on reposting of existing questions, for any reason.

Comment: @J.Steen, that's possibly because the re-open queue takes too long to process, that's the downside of closing as early (not disputing there are upsides to it too). It reminds me of [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261435/372643).

Comment: ok. understandable. I just wish people would explain sometimes. I can't avoid mistakes if I don't know them.  For example, @mario, I didn't know what other details you were asking for and I still don't know where else to ask for advise. My apologies if this is the wrong place. I typed "stackoverflow support" into google and it lead me to the meta page.. I read a couple of questions and it seemed like the right place. One moment while I get the link to the duplicate.Thanks for the help people!!  to those who got offended and voted this down, srry but i dont understand all this. I'm trying.

Comment: @Bruno The reopen votes queue is nearly constantly empty for me, on both meta and main. How do you mean slow?

Comment: How can I edit my posts? whenever I edit it says another user has already edited the post.

Comment: Ok, your dupe is opened, and I removed the rant-like part of this question.

Comment: J.Steen said it sounds like a rant so I wanted to reword but it says I can't?

Comment: @J.Steen, not sure how the queue itself works, but whenever I've voted for thing to get re-opened, it's always taken ages (I mean days at least). Sometimes, to the point the re-open flag had expired (so your re-open vote is discarded, but you can't vote to re-open again).

Comment: @Bruno Maybe (just speculating here) that's because enough people have deemed those particular questions unworthy to be reopened? I'm not putting any judgement into their being wrong or not, just stating a speculative reason.

Comment: @J.Steen, but the closing behaviour is heavily biased towards closing I find. Perhaps some people relieve their frustration of the day by saying "I don't like that question" in the close queue ("I've had a bad day" -> "The world annoys me" -> "I don't really understand what that guy's asking about but it just doesn't smell right" -> "Vote to close"), and an equal number of people who're just indifferent to opening and closing (in doubt, use skip). The benefit of the doubt doesn't always apply on SO. (I'm speculating too.)

Comment: @Bruno: There is an initial delay before a post enters the reopen queue (about 30 minutes, IIRC). After that, it depends on the site how quickly a post makes it through the voting process. On Stack Overflow and on Meta SO, that can be *very fast indeed*. In this specific case,  about 45 minutes had passed when I saw it in the queue. *That is not a very long time*. It had 2 'leave closed' votes on it before the post was deleted.

Comment: @Bruno: This is not the place for a debate on what is reopen worthy or not *in general*, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sorry, I wasn't talking about this specific question indeed. I'm just saying that sometimes questions are closed (duplicates or not) because the voters don't quite understand them in details. Since those who might vote to re-open don't necessarily understand their object (possibly niche questions), some questions stay closed forever, or at least for a long time.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a reopen queue. I edited my question and thought there would be an indication on the actual post to inform me that something would be done, etc.  Once I made changes, I saw duplicate and thought it was just being overlooked. My apologies. now I know though!  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sorry that you feel that your question should not have been closed as a duplicate. As already stated on the [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265193/website-doesnt-track-days-visited) (deleted, 10k+ only) *and* on the [repost you made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265198/website-doesnt-track-days-visited), the information you seek is **not public**. As such, all we can give you is already answered in the duplicate target. *Noone can give you any more information on the topic*. I and others have repeatedly tried to tell you so, please do listen to such feedback.

The *normal* procedure to handle a duplicate dispute, is to edit your question to clarify what you were looking for. You did so with your original post, and it appeared in the reopen queue for review.

However, 2 people (including me) felt that your question is still a duplicate, and voted to leave it closed, before you deleted the post. Had you not deleted it, there would have been a (small) chance that others disagreed and reopened your post.

Please, do *not* just delete and repost questions that have been closed. Doing so repeatedly can get you banned from posting new questions, as you are creating more noise than is deemed appropriate.

Comment: ++ just out of curiosity: does the same mechanism of getting banned apply here on meta as on the SO?

Comment: @mehow: no, I don't think so. It'd require a manual ban (which *may* have to apply to both Meta and the main site, not sure).

Comment: Ok no worries maybe I should post this as a new question

Comment: Ok cool beans! Thanks again everyone for your help. Sorry if my frustration became an inconvenience. I wasn't initially understanding that the information I was asking for wasn't public. I thought the person's reply was opinionated based on the way they stated it. I understand now though and thanks again everyone!!

Comment: @cjayem13: Glad to have been of help! And I wish more 'upset' people on the internet were able to regain their calm like you just did. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters  [new question here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265212/does-the-same-mechanism-for-an-automatic-question-ban-apply-on-mso) if you're interested