# Does the same mechanism for an automatic question ban apply on MSO?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, post-ban

Say a new user (low rep) is constantly asking the same question over and over which is getting downvoted and closed *as duplicate or any other reason which applies*. That user keeps deleting the downvoted and closed questions and reposting the same content as a new question.

- Does that qualify for an automatic question-ban?
- If yes, is he banned from both SO and MSO in this case?
- If not, is there any other way than flagging one of his posts with custom reason to report such bad behaviour and making moderators aware which may decide to issue a manual ban?

Comment: "Issue a manual ban" - question bans are always automatic.  A moderator can't impose or lift them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The automatic question bans aren't usually enabled on meta sites. However, the low quality automatic answer bans are.

Users can't be suspended on meta sites alone. If they're suspended then it has to be from the main account. If you see something you think we should be aware of then flag any of their posts using the "Other" option and we'll look into it. If you can flag one of the disruptive posts then all the better, but it's not essential as we can see their deleted posts.

If someone is being disruptive on meta then a suspension on both sites *is* warranted.

Comment: Ok therefore there is no automatic mechanism here that detects potentially malicious users. is that correct?

Comment: @Payeli - They were only getting a warning about the downsides of deleting an existing question, which I think is a system holdover from the main site. The question ban is disabled for Meta.SO. It still does exist on Meta.SE, although much less strict than on SO proper.

Comment: @Payeli - There is no such thing as a manual question ban. It's all done by the system, and nobody can control that.

Comment: What is the low-quality answer ban? I hope it's not based just on downvotes. I also don't see why a user who is disruptive on meta should be suspended from main. Some people have trouble controlling themselves in a relatively "free" environment but can behave well and be useful in a more constrained one.

Comment: @dfeuer: Of course there are a number of other factors - just think of the answer ban as the answer counterpart to a question ban. I agree with you that suspension on meta should be separate from main.

Comment: It would be pretty silly to have automatic question bans (except spam, offensive, etc) on meta sites where downvotes mean disagreement, not low-quality stuff.

Comment: @FinalContest they mean disagreement mostly on feature-requests which could have easily been excluded

Comment: @vba4all: And burninate-requests, and arguably some discussions, and...