# What are the criteria for low-quality automatic answer bans on meta sites?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, meta, post-ban

Related:

[Does the same mechanism for an automatic question ban apply on MSO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265212/does-the-same-mechanism-for-an-automatic-question-ban-apply-on-mso)

[Is negative rep on Meta taken into Consideration for a Question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265912/is-negative-rep-on-meta-taken-into-consideration-for-a-question-ban)

[Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

In first related question, ChrisF said this:

> The automatic question bans aren't usually enabled on meta sites.
>   However, the *low quality automatic answer bans* are.

Can you explain what are the criteria that matches "low quality answers" in meta sites (MSO, MSU, etc.)? How it being enforced to weeding noises out?

Also, is it true that downvotes on meta answers doesn't cause any harm to meta account standing (except on MSE)?

**Background:** I posted answers as personal thoughts for SE sites on featured questions other than in MSE (tagged with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)) and getting some downvotes, I felt probably someone within the community just express his/her disagreement with certain reasons. As featured questions are viewed as [media for SE company to communicate with the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), I think the answers on those questions should be treated like questions which has [featured-request](/questions/tagged/featured-request) tag.

NB: This is likely similar but not totally the same thing as [What are the criteria for low-quality posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251820/what-are-the-criteria-for-low-quality-posts), since the linked question asked LQP criteria for main site but I want to ask which LQP criteria applies for meta instead.

Comment: quality is determined by voting

Comment: Have you experienced an actual problem here, or are you just worrying preemptively?

Comment: @CodyGray I just curious what ChrisF stated in his post, actually I don't hitting any kind of ban yet. But preventing such hassle to be happened is better than try getting out of it.