# Weekday warrior badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request

SO already has the Enthusiast (30 consecutive days) and Fanatic (100 consecutive days) badges, but I was thinking maybe there should be a Weekday Warrior badge that you get if you visit the site M-F for 4/6/N weeks in a row.

Thoughts?

Comment: Wouldn't that be redundant? Or is it an attempt to cater to users who don't / can't visit the site during week-ends?

Comment: So what about those that only can visit on weekends? What about those that do visit all the days of the week, will they get *three* badges then?

Comment: I made it a habit to open SO on my phone every Saturday and Sunday when waking up. Just loading the site is enough to mark the day as *visited*. If you really want the badge, I suggest you do the same.

Comment: @Stijn loading the site may not be enough to register a visit according to this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251766/57475

Comment: @Tanner yet all I did was open SO, go to my profile and see that the day had registered by opening the calendar.

Comment: @Stijn fair enough, I'll remember to check that as I'm 53 days into my 100 :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a good point.  I'd think that the badges that include weekends would trump/supersede the weekday badges, because the weekday visits are implied.  And yes, it would be aimed at people who use SO for work, but don't visit it on the weekends.

Comment: It isn't remarkable asking/answering on weekdays.  That's usually when we are more likely to be around here.  A badge for answering questions on the weekends would probably be a better idea.

Comment: I'm always disappointed when I see complaints about how the Fanatic badge should be easier to get. If it's hard to get, you're not a fanatic.

Comment: @Stijn, I did the same and was hoping Fanatic badge can awarded multiple times...

Comment: What about holidays? They are very different across locations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Badges are used to encourage or discourage user behaviour. For something to be worth a badge, it must be something that Stack Exchange wants to encourage or discourage.

Stack Overflow gets more than enough visits during the weekdays, so there is no need to encourage it with a badge.
The opposite of what you propose would be more likely: a badge to encourage presence during the weekend. However, presence during the weekend is already encouraged by the existing "Enthusiast" and "Fanatic" badges.

As is indicated in the comments under your question, getting the "Enthusiast" and "Fanatic" badge isn't that difficult, assuming you have internet access during the weekend. 
Do keep in mind that the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges are based on UTC - more than one person attempting to get these badges has missed a day, and needed to start again, because of this.