# Second time that Stack Overflow's daily visits counter resets for "fanatic" badge

Tags: support, badges, consecutive-days

I'm going for the "fanatic" badge which is awarded for visiting Stack Overflow for 100 consecutive days. The first time it reset, I was disappointed (I was a day away from the 30 consecutive days badge), because I was confident that I had logged in the day prior. Especially since I'm doing the same thing on the Super User site, and that counter hasn't reset. After a couple of minutes of frustration and reflecting I assumed that I was just wrong. Perhaps I must just logged in after the timezone difference, etc...

But it happened again today. I am positive I logged on yesterday within the timezone especially since my Super User account **and** my Stack Overflow counter both increased by one from the day previous. My Super User account is still accurate.

What is going on? Is this user error (not being active enough even though I log on everyday?) or is this some weird Stack Overflow issue? Here's some more information that goes to show my level of confidence that it's not user error.

1. I use LastPass so anytime I go to either site, I'm automatically logged in. To confirm this I always check my current counter to make sure it's increased by one, then I will do at least one of the following to confirm that I'm logged in and being active; post, edit, up/downvote. Is only doing one of these things considered "not active" enough to Stacks standards? If so, what is this standard?
2. I've created a script that acts as a kind of alarm clock. It prompts 2-3 times at times when I'm surely at my desk. It will open SO/SU websites as sort of a reminder. It does this at specific times, respective to the 24 hour timezone limit.
3. Again, I'm trying for the 'fanatic' badge on two sites at the same time. So far, Super User hasn't had a hiccup and is at 40+ consecutive days. Stack Overflow's counter has reset twice, right before the 30 day marker.

Comment: You need to be *active*; logging in alone is not enough. What exactly counts as *active* is not public.

Comment: I mentioned that. I am active. I don't just "log in." I read up on that the first time the counter reset. I post, edit, and/or up/downvote, every time I log on.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251762/how-does-stack-overflow-keep-track-of-visit-timestamps

Comment: You aren't disputing your [activities](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4421333/bitinerary?tab=activity&sort=all), right?

Comment: @rene Good point, but we can't see votes here.

Comment: @BiTinerary I keep wondering why you go to all these lengths to acquire a badge in a (to me) somewhat disputable manner. Just do whatever you like to do at SO and these badges will come - or not. Personally I never worry about badges. When they come, it's usually the first time I'm even aware of their existence.

Comment: @GertArnold with 68 votes casted, 0 helpful flags and 3 edits I don't think seeing votes will change much ...

Comment: But we can congratulate this user with their new [quorum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum?userid=4421333) badge...that is not the badge this post is about but still....

Answer (score 44):

There are a number of things you need to remember.

1. The Stack Exchange "day" is based on UTC so you need to work out a local time that's somewhere in the middle of the UTC "day" to ensure that you have some leeway in when you visit. I can see you're based in the US which is 5-8 hours behind UTC. So if you visit at noon every day you should get the badge. You might be able to choose a more convenient time depending on exactly where in the US you are.
2. You need to do more than just load the home page (`https://stackoverflow.com`) to register as a "visit" for the badge. This may include viewing question pages, your profile or any other page. It's not guaranteed to be just one of these other pages either. The exact criteria aren't public though, so even if I knew I couldn't tell you.

Comment: I mention the timezone issue and "just visiting" aspects several times in the post.

Comment: @BiTinerary. I know that. But getting Enthusiastic and Fanatic is easy if you follow the rules.

Comment: This (the 2nd point) is not true. I got the Fanatic badge just by opening my StackOverflow mobile app daily

Comment: @Adelin - I'm pretty sure that opening the mobile app doesn't just load `https://stackoverflow.com` and would, therefore, count as a visit.

Comment: The 2 point disapponted me as well. I've had 51 day, checked on Saturday the feed - nothing interesting. Turned off. And on Sunday here we are: 1/100. Disclaimer: I'm an active user/contributor of SO for 8 years. I give up, stackoverflow. I am not that fanatic of ambiguity.

Comment: This seems to be a nearly exact duplicate of someone else's answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251766/1271772

Answer (score -3):

I visited the site as usual for 88 consecutive days. Yup 88... When I logged in today it ended up showing my count as 1 ...I was frustrated.

Reason: **"VPN"**

**"DO NOT KEEP YOUR VPN ON"** while logging in or you'll end up resenting it