# Fanatic badge reset to 0 while I have been visiting site

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow is like a social networking site to me. Till yesterday, Stack Overflow was showing my progress on the Fanatic badge (30 some days) and today it has been reset to one. [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) was also showing my progress yesterday, and it didn't reset. Why is it so??

I have read the question *[Second time that Stack Overflow's daily visits counter resets for "fanatic" badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298530/second-time-that-stack-overflows-daily-visits-counter-resets-for-fanatic-badg)*, but it doesn't fit in my case as I am truly "proactive" as already told, Stack Overflow is like my Social networking site.

Comment: Days are counted in UTC. If you go to your profile, you can click on the visited XX days, YY consecutive to see when you visited.

Comment: Yes and UTC begins at 5AM my time while my counter was live mere at last night