# What is "meaningful activity"?

Tags: support, terminology

In the *"[Email + Privacy] The power to choose"* email sent out by SO recently, one of the statements is:

> As part of our new data-retention policy, we will now delete accounts that have been inactive for more than two years and where the user has never engaged in any meaningful activity.

I couldn't see in the updated [Public Network ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service) or [Privacy Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) any definition of what constitutes *"meaningful"* activity.

What does it include?

---

Note:

This question has been identified as a duplicate of [As per the new data retention policy, when will inactive accounts now be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310446/as-per-the-new-data-retention-policy-when-will-inactive-accounts-now-be-deleted) on MSE.

Comment: My guess its it's the activity shown in your profile, which is basically any action that you take that's not just reading things.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the list of activities that would count toward badges like fanatic?  [An exhaustive list of activities that could as being active is not public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298532/4320665)

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm sure that would be classed as activity, but meaningful? I don't think you need to do much besides read a few posts/vote once on something to get a days activity (if that)

Comment: Similar question on MSE... not answered yet, though. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310446/as-per-the-new-data-retention-policy-when-will-inactive-accounts-now-be-deleted

Comment: @Catija I think similar is an understatement haha

Comment: They don't know yet, it will be implemented in 6 to 8 weeks. If it involves  SQL the query needs to meet the *doesn't make Nick Craver sad* criteria.

Comment: Question is answered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310446/as-per-the-new-data-retention-policy-when-will-inactive-accounts-now-be-deleted/310516?noredirect=1#comment1014378_310516

Comment: @AnitaTaylor Thanks Anita, I've put it as an additional answer here (Personally I don't use MSE)

Comment: @NickA yes, I was able to get Fanatic on a few sites where some of the days were just viewing a few questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anita Taylor (Senior Product Marketing Manager at SO), has posted an answer over at [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310516), quoted here for those that aren't active on MSE.

> As you can imagine, we have a large number of users who essentially opened an account, never did anything, forgot they created an account and stopped visiting the site.
>
> Rather than holding on to that data forever, we plan to delete an account if a user:
>
> - hasn't visited the site in the last two years
> - never asked or answered a question
> - has a reputation under 2
> - doesn't have a Developer Story or hasn't applied to a job or job search status ≠ actively looking
> - hasn't opened or clicked any promotional email in the last year.
>     As you can see, we are really targeting users who really, truly don't use our site.
>
> Affected users will be notified via email one week before the deletion is scheduled to take place, with instructions on how to reactivate their account. (Essentially, all they have to do is visit their Stack Exchange community and log in.)

Comment: This will remove at most [1,960,435](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855464) user accounts on SO.(can't check in SEDE if users have a dev-story or clicked on an email)